# Transfer WordPress blog to own domain

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to WordPress:-

I have one WordPress blog [`https://ruchisrasoi.wordpress.com/`](https://ruchisrasoi.wordpress.com/)

now I want to move my own domain `ruchisrasoi.com` with own server.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

This is a duplicate of [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27694239/how-to-download-wordpress-source-code)

> What you can do is follow this link:
>   http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/wordpress/transfer-wordpress/
>
> It basically shows you how to migrate the data. You will need to setup
>   wordpress.org on your new location first then once both are up, you
>   can export from wordpress.com to your new location using I think a
>   migration wordpress plugin. This should bring over your database. You
>   will need to figure out how to migrate the template and style (look
>   and feel) of the site. You may want to just find a new template that
>   you like because I don't know how compatible wordpress.com templates
>   are.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Instead of just copy and pasting it you should vote to close as dupe instead.